# What parameters would go in the brackets just after the name of a class?

Tags: python, class, definition

This is how I am defining a class:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

So, when defining a class, the parameters to be passed for initialization are in the brackets immediately after the `__init__` method.

My question is, what is supposed to be in, or what is the point of, the brackets just after the name of the class `Foo`.

I've looked around, but everything I have been able to find so far has either not actually put anything in those brackets, or *has* put something in, but hasn't explained why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A superclass name. Read about *inheritance*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as @Christian mentioned, you can specify the superclass of `Foo` inside the brackets:

```
class Bar: pass
class Foo(Bar): #Foo is subclass of Bar now
    pass
```

by default, if `Foo` doesn't inherit any class, just omit the `()`:

```
class Foo: #this creates old-style classes in python2, which is not suggested
    ....
```

generally, we inherit from `object` (in python2) to create [new-style classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) when writing our custom classes:

```
class Foo(object):
    ....
```

Comment: The defautl case of omitting the brackets is valid only for Python 3 - in Python 2 you should inherit all classes from "object", or risk having them misbehaving in strange ways. `class Bar(object):pass`

Comment: So in Python 2, inheritance wasn't possible?

Comment: @xander from where do you get that conclusion?

Comment: oh dear, sorry... Somehow misread @jsbueno's comment above. Oops.

Comment: @xander: of course it was (ad is) possible - you use the brackets after the class name the same way. We are talking about optionally suppressing the brackets if you are not inheriting of anything meaningful - which works for both versions. Only that will create undesirable "old style" classes in Python 2 due to backward compatibility issues with pre-python 2.2 code.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters that go into the bracket after the class name is the name of the class to be inherited.

```
    class Parent:
        pass

    class Child(Parent):
        pass
```